# Why has my code disappeared on an older project?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Bit of an odd problem here I can't seem to figure out.. I have an older project that sends e-mails to SMS numbers. I haven't touched it in about 5 months and decided to revisit today. However, when I loaded the project all of the code is gone and the form1 design is as well. No changes have been made or anything since I last messed with it back in May. The odd part is that when I hit 'Play' the form loads up with the dropdown still populated and everything.. Has anyone encountered this or know of a way to get the code/design form back?

Attaching a few images to try and show what I'm talking about.

[Form Open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98CM8.png)

[Form Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4K1S.png)

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that your some of the file got hidden. May be you can try to see all files in your project location by clicking **Show All Files** icon from solution explorer and then you have to include them in your project again to see it through visual studio.

[image]